# Python sort data in lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

We have three different lists:

```
1th = [(442, 248), (442, 249), (442, 250), (442, 251), (442, 252), (442, 253), (442, 254), (442, 255), (442, 256), (442, 257), (442, 258), (442, 259), (442, 260), (442, 261)]
2nd = [(96, 128, 144), (112, 128, 144), (80, 96, 96), (32, 48, 48), (64, 64, 64), (64, 64, 64), (32, 32, 32), (16, 16, 0), (16, 16, 0), (16, 16, 0), (16, 16, 0), (16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32)]
3-rd = [(16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32)]
```

A program needs to take a value from the 3rd list (let's call it "**Etalon**" value), compare it with data from second and if it the same must takes value with the index from list 2 and taken value program must add in list 3 after Etalon.

The result must be like:

```
[((16, 16, 16), (442, 255), (442, 256), (442, 257), (442, 258)), ((32, 32, 32),(442, 248), (442, 249), (442, 250))]
```

All data above are RGB colors, xy coordinates and prompt to sort pixels to color.

Question is: which method needs to be used to add an element to 3rd list with specific index? I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
3-rd.append(1th[index from 2nd])
```

Comment: "doesn't work as I need"... Can you post any errors you are getting, or the incorrect output?

Comment: 3-rd.append(1th[index from 2nd]) takes [(16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32), (442, 248), (442, 249), (442, 250), (442, 251), (442, 252)] e.q [RGB, RGB, XY,XY,XY]  needs [RGB, XY,XY,XY, RGB XY,XY,XY]

Comment: Although these are most likely examples, `1th`, `2nd` and `3-rd` are not valid variable names in Python. Or English, for that matter.

Comment: please read 1-th, 2-nd, 3-rd read as "first python list", "second" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
first = [(442, 248), (442, 249), (442, 250), (442, 251), (442, 252), (442, 253), (442, 254), (442, 255), (442, 256), (442, 257), (442, 258), (442, 259), (442, 260), (442, 261)]
second = [(96, 128, 144), (112, 128, 144), (80, 96, 96), (32, 48, 48), (64, 64, 64), (64, 64, 64), (32, 32, 32), (16, 16, 16), (16, 16, 16), (16, 16, 16), (16, 16, 0), (16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32)]
third = [(16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32)]            

output = []

for v3 in third:
    f = True
    run = []
    for i2, v2 in enumerate(second):
        if v3 == v2:
            if f:
                run.append(v3)
                f = False

            run.append(first[i2])

    if run:
        output.append(run)

print output
```

This produces the output:

```
[[(16, 16, 16), (442, 255), (442, 256), (442, 257), (442, 259)], [(32, 32, 32), (442, 254), (442, 260)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a an insert() method which allows you to insert an element at a specific index inside a list.

```
list_name = ["a", "b", "d"]

list_name.insert(2,"d")

print list_name

#prints ['a', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
first = pd.Series([(442, 248), (442, 249), (442, 250), (442, 251), (442, 252), (442, 253), (442, 254), (442, 255), (442, 256), (442, 257), (442, 258), (442, 259), (442, 260), (442, 261)])
second = pd.Series([(96, 128, 144), (112, 128, 144), (80, 96, 96), (32, 48, 48), (64, 64, 64), (64, 64, 64), (32, 32, 32), (16, 16, 16), (16, 16, 16), (16, 16, 16), (16, 16, 0), (16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32)])

third = [(16, 16, 16), (32, 32, 32)] 

res = [ [item] + first[ second[ second == item].index ].tolist() for item in third]

[[(16, 16, 16), (442, 255), (442, 256), (442, 257), (442, 259)], [(32, 32, 32), (442, 254), (442, 260)]]
```